# trying to center images in a sidebar

Tags: image, center

[enter link description here](http://hallmusicstudio.phinhall.net/)

this is the site in question, the div that I am trying to target?

img.side-class is the selector , and ideas ?

Comment: I didn't understand you !

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get it in the middle of that div is

```
    img.side-class {
        margin-left: 12px;
    }
```

Comment: But will it be responsive?

Comment: That was not a responsive fix. Looks like you found one though with text-align: center;  Nice work.